# What happens with TCPClient after its NetworkStream is passed out of scope? is it disposed?

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream

I wonder what happens when I first create a `TCPClient` within a function scope, extract the `NetworkStream` out of it, pass that to the c-tor of a class and return the newly created object:

```
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    await client.ConnectAsync(host, outport).ConfigureAwait(false);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    TCPWrapperAdapterWithStream adapter = new TCPWrapperAdapterWithStream(stream, stream, 100);
    return adapter;
}
```

What happens with client after the context is left? Will stream still be working?
Can I do it in this way or do I have to "keep" the `TCPClient` object?

Comment: did you run into an issue while debugging your program?

Comment: surprisingly not. But how can it be?

Comment: well.. it's a little out of my knowledge and expertise, but it really comes down to GC tracking behavior on the `NetworkStream` type instance and it's reference\usage through the app (or other function scopes).  I think TCPClient would persist here if adapter is persisted, for reclaiming it seems problematic - but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCPClient starts throwing if you continue to use it. I ended up filing a bug when I discovered SSLStream threw for no good reason in Dispose because it called TCPClient.Flush() which threw when NetworkStream was dead.

(I needed to shutdown SSLStream immediately because I knew it was dead in a way that it was going to block for seconds before failing if closed the normal way so I tried this.)

On the other hand, TCPClient will attempt to dispose its NetworkStream in the finalizer. I got bit by this once ages ago.

Comment: but I do not use TCPClient anymore, just its NetworkStream.

Comment: @MichaelW: Then the finalizer hates your guts.